# String Concatenation - eloquent javascript chess board

Tags: javascript, string, eloquent, concatenation, chess

Why isn't this string concatenating on one line? I am not "\n" breaking the line, shouldn't it log to the console like " # # # #"?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var str = "";
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    str += "#";
  else
    str += " ";
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *console.log* function. It logs result of your expression on single line. Your code works like this: you just log ' ', than *#*, than ' ' and so on. If you want  *# # # #*, you should not overwrite *str* on every iteration, but make one string with all values. Use this:

```
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
     str += "#";
  } else {
     str += " ";
  }     
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @DrewT, it depends from what side you are looking at it. This code deals with _str_ and _console.log_. Original code was rewriting _str_ variable as well as using _console.log_ in wrong place. Author  wanted to get " # # # #", not 8 strings. But I will make it more clear in my post.

Comment: This answer is leading the discussion down the wrong path. It's perfectly ok to `console.log()` values inside of a for loop, you will just get multiple console.logs for each iteration of the loop. The real reason this code works is because of moving the var declaration outside of the for loop so it is not constantly overwriting itself and in turn giving actual usefulness to using the `+=` operator

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic. The function `console.log` is for js debugging it's not for printing values to the screen or for using that value at that particular breakpoint. If you are not getting the expected output it's always best practice to log your values at iteration so you can debug what the interpreter is actually doing.

Comment: @DrewT, read it correctly. It uses console.log as well as as _str_ variable. I just made it clear what _console.log_ loged and after that I said about storing it in one variable instead overriding it. You can complain as much as you want but author calls _console.log_ several times as well as rewriting _str_. I made an answer to correct both mistakes and my code does what author wants. You just made wrong example, your log isn't _ # # # #_ and you tell me I am wrong. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Hey @Lends I'm sorry that I seem to have offended you, it was never my intention. I'm also not attempting to complain and I don't care about downvotes as I have a decent reputation on SO. I seriously was just trying to clarify things, because I do believe that your post, although being syntactically correct from a code standpoint, doesn't explain why OP never got "# # # #" at any iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @DrewT, I think `you should not rewrite str on every iteration` is pretty clear.

Comment: Hey @Lends it's probably just a language barrier with SO being in English but I do think you mean `overwrite` not `rewrite`. Change that unclear word and I'll gladly give you an upvote and add +10 your reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at what's happening *inside* your `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var str = "";     // set `str` to an empty string
  if (i % 2 == 0)   // append "#" or " " to `str`
    str += "#";
  else
    str += " ";
  console.log(str); // write `str` the console
}
```

Everything between `{` and `}` will happen eight times, so you're creating an empty string eight times and you're calling `console.log` eight times.

If you want to create an empty string *one* time, append `"#"` or `" "` to it eight times, and then call `console.log` *one* time, you need to do some of those things outside of your `for` loop:

```
var str = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    str += "#";
  } else {
    str += " ";
  }
}

console.log(str);
// => # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the scope of your initial var declaration. What your code is doing is always concatenating the value when the var is equal to "". This is because the var gets reset at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop because of the line `var str = "";` being inside of the for loop. What you have to do is move the initial declaration outside of your for loop:

```
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    str += "#";
  else
    str += " ";
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: This will still result in # \n # \n # \n # \n instead of # # # #. You need to call console.log outside of the loop to get it all on one line.

Comment: That is just not true, the difference in logging values inside the for loop is only that it will log the concatenation at each instance of the for loop which is better for debugging. For example testing it in the JS console produces this output: http://screencast.com/t/1zfp1rrSIvo